# Terraform map require key to be set and accept any optional keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to allow any key to be set within a dictionary object and require `Name` to be set. Im passing this object into a variable that forces `Name` to be set but its ignoring all the other keys

```
tags   = {
  "Name"        = "EC2_Name_Value"  # Required
  "AnyKey1"        = "value1"
  "AnyKey2"        = "value2"
...
}

variable "tags" {
  type = object({
    Name = string
  })
}
```

```
> var.tags
{
  "Name" = "EC2_Name_Value"
}
```

I know that I'm able to use `key = optional(string)` however, i want to accept all extra keys and not have to define only the keys i want to accept.

Answer (score 3):

What I would suggest is leaving the `tags` variable as is (maybe renaming it), and then using either an additional variable or local variables, e.g.:

```
variable "required_tag" {
  type = object({
    Name = string
  })
}

variable "additional_tags" {
  type = object(any)
}
```

Then, you would use the `merge` built-in function [1] to bring them all together:

```
tags = merge(var.required_tag, var.additional_tags)
```

Alternatively, since you know you will always need that one tag, you could switch it up a bit and remove the `required_tag` (or `tags` in your example) variable, and do something like:

```
tags = merge({ Name = "EC2_Name_Value" }, var.additional_tags)
```

Last, but not the least, there is an option to use `default_tags` on the provider level [2], but I am not sure if that fits your case.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/resource-tagging#propagating-tags-to-all-resources